# How to fetch data from dynamodb with Keycondition expression with sort key timestamp?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am facing some issue with querying data from DynamoDB can any one of you help me on this? I am coding in NodeJS.

My table looks like below with,

```
Primary key: RequestId
Secondary index: Userid with sortkey Timestamp
```

When I am pulling the data using UserId, I am getting lot's for records so, planning to pull the data with Timestamp condition.

RequestId Request Timestamp UserId

```
var doc = require("dynamodb-doc"); 
var dynamo = new doc.DynamoDB();
var userid_col = "amzn1.ask.account.AGCAPY7JBHQWHTNGAHJJ"; 
var databaserec = { TableName: "dna_cdknow_prod_historylog", 
    IndexName: "UserId-TimeStamp-index", 
    KeyConditionExpression: "UserId = :input", 
    FilterExpression : 'created between :val1 and :val2', 
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{ ":input": userid_col, ":val1" : "2016-05-23T00:00:00Z", ":val2" : "2017-05-23T16:20:49Z" } };
```

Comment: Code,
var doc = require("dynamodb-doc");
var dynamo = new doc.DynamoDB();
var userid_col = "amzn1.ask.account.AGCAPY7JBHQWHTNGAHJJ";

var databaserec = {
    TableName: "dna_cdknow_prod_historylog",
    IndexName: "UserId-TimeStamp-index",
    KeyConditionExpression: "UserId = :input",
    FilterExpression : 'created between :val1 and :val2',
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{
        ":input": userid_col,
        ":val1" : "2016-05-23T00:00:00Z",
        ":val2" : "2017-05-23T16:20:49Z"
    }
};

Comment: What is the problem? It is not clear. Are you getting any error / exception?

Comment: I am not getting databack from database and also not clear how to write KeyConditionExpression...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should work if the GSI definition is as follows:-

```
UserId - Partition key of GSI
created - Sort key of GSI
```

**Corrected code:-**

```
var databaserec = { 
    TableName: "dna_cdknow_prod_historylog", 
    IndexName: "UserId-TimeStamp-index", 
    KeyConditionExpression: "UserId = :input AND created between :val1 and :val2'",     
    ExpressionAttributeValues:{ ":input": userid_col, ":val1" : "2016-05-23T00:00:00Z", ":val2" : "2017-05-23T16:20:49Z" }  
}; 

docClient.query(databaserec, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
        console.log(params);
        console.log("Query succeeded.");        
        data.Items.forEach(function(item) {
            console.log("Item :" + JSON.stringify(item));           
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Now it's working perfectly fine.. i have faced some issues with permeation and also with reserved keywords. Permeations were resolved by AWS admin team and the timestamp column i have replaced with ExpressionAttributeNames :). Thank you for all your support....

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it was helpful? Thanks